# Relation on torsion free sheaf and locally free sheaf in the analytic setting

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

It is well known that  a torsion free sheaf  is also locally free  on a curve, in the algebraic geometry category.   A further fact is that  **a torsion free sheaf  is locally free outside a Zariski closed subset of codimension $\geq 2$** on a higher dimension normal variety.  Those results can be found in   Proposition 5.1.6 or Proposition 5.1.7  in  the book *Introduction to Singularities*
Shihoko Ishii,  https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-4-431-56837-7.pdf

**My question:  can those results still hold in the analytic setting?**

Comment: If the curve is not locally irreducible, the structure sheaf will not be torsion free. If the curve is smooth, this still holds in the analytic setting, because the ring of convergent power series is a PID.

Comment: @red_trumpet  Thank you.  Assume normal condition. Normal points are locally  irreducible points. But how to get the local freeness from the torsion freeness of a sheaf over a smooth higher-dimensional complex manifold? What the role does the "not locally irreducible"  condition play? Can you talk more precisely on  this condition?

Comment: If $x$ is a point where locally two components $X, Y$ meet, then the stalk $\mathcal O_x$ will contain zero-divisors. If $f \in \mathcal O_x$ is a function germ which is zero on $X$ and non-zero on $Y$, and $g \in \mathcal O_x$ vanishes on $Y$, but not on $X$, then $fg = 0$. So even the (free) structure sheaf will have torsion.

Comment: I can't really help with the higher-dimensional case. Maybe take a look at Grauert's and Remmert's *Coherent analytic sheaves*, they prove that any coherent sheaf is locally free outside a nowhere dense analytic subset (p. 92). Though I don't know if this can be improved by assuming torsion free.

Comment: @LelongWang - you may be aware of this: If your curve $C \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ is complex and projective, it follows (see Hartshorne, the appendix) there is an equivalence of categories between the "category of coherent analytic sheaves" on $C$ and "coherent sheaves" on the corresponding algebraic curve $C^{alg}$. This may prove your case when $C$ is projective.